# Можно ли использовать память жесткого диска вместо оперативной для переменных в коде?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

Есть программа, которая принимает список xlsx файлов и прогоняет их построчно по очереди, достает нужные сведения и сопоставляет их между собой (ищет совпадения в файлах, сопоставляет их и так далее..)
Выглядит примерно так:

```
key_info = {}
for file in tuple_of_files:
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file, read_only=True)
    first_sheet = wb.sheetnames[0]
    for row in wb[first_sheet].rows:
        #тут фрагмент кода чтобы достать из строки нужный объект, который мы сохраняем в переменную var_info
        if var_info not in key_info:
            key_info[var_info] = {'count' : 1, 'reg' : None, 'oper' : None, 'time_use' : set(),  'imeis' : set()}
            #далее фрагмент кода по вычислению и заполнению подсловаря для этого объекта
        elif var_info in key_info:
            key_info[var_info]['count'] += 1
            key_info[var_info]['time_use'].add(some_info)
            key_info[var_info]['imeis'].add(some_other_info)
```

Потом используя словарь с ключевыми значениями `key_info` создаю xlsx файл и записываю в него результаты анализа.
Программа работает, пока общее число строк в передаваемых ей файлах не превышает примерно 1млн, и в целом делает свою работу. Но когда пытаешься передать файлы с большим объемом (к примеру общее число строк около 5млн), то возникает ошибка memoryError.
Я понимаю, что это из-за того, что словарь key_info просто уже не может вмещать информацию, однако разбить его на несколько других файлов или обнулять через определенное число строк, никак не получится - теряется весь функционал проверки.

Есть ли какой-нибудь способ сохранять этот словарь `key_info` не в оперативной памяти, а на жестком диске и работать с ним по той же схеме?

Пытался реализовать путем создания вместо словаря базу данных SQLite на жестком диске и работать с ней по аналогичному алгоритму, но тогда по мере ее наполнения скорость SELECT/UPDATE катастрофически падает и весь анализ занимает огромное количество времени. К примеру анализ 1млн строк с использованием словаря составляет в среднем 600 секунд, с использованием SQLite (для сравнения созданной как на жестком диске, так и в оперативной памяти) - 4800 секунд (и скорость падает еще сильнее по мере наполнения базы)...

Comment: А может вам просто записывать все эти данные в базу как есть, а потом уже аггрегировать опять же запросами к базе?  У вас же там просто список получается, мне кажется проще собрать список из базы потом, а не держать это всё в питоне.

Comment: Опять же проще будет разбираться что именно тормозит, если разнести запись и генерацию отчёта на две разные операции.

Comment: @CrazyElf Я бы скинул файл с результатом, который я хочу получить, и фрагмент кода по заполнению и обновлению базы SQL с комментариями, но из-за того, что я новый участник StackOverflow для меня закрыт чат..

Comment: Каким образом вы пробовали использовать БД? Если делали так, что данные `key_info` вместо памяти хранились в БД и каждое изменение требовало чтение и запись в БД, то такой подход будет на порядок медленнее чем обработка в памяти. Нужно переносить именно сами агрегации в БД, т.е. вместо кода в питоне, должен быть запрос SQL.

Comment: Оценивали ли вы сколько реально данных нужно хранить в памяти? Вопрос к тому, что возможно доступной памяти, в принципе, для этого алгоритма хватит, но из-за того, что память используется неоптимально (например, обработанные файлы все еще находятся в памяти) или не используется вовсе (например, используется 32-битный питон, который не может видеть больше 4Гб) памяти не хватает. Так можно было бы обойтись без существенных изменений только за счет оптимизации собственно использования памяти. Но для этого нужно оценить поместится ли все, что нужно хранить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не уверен насколько это поможет, но я бы попробовал хранить все в БД + для ускорения хранить в кеше какое то кол-во записей из key_info, чтобы меньше дергать БД

Что то типа этого

```
class CacheKeyInfo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.max_contains = 100000  # размер кеша, чтобы не было memoryError
        self.key_info_cache = {}  # сам кеш
        self.key_info_contains = set()  # названия всех встречавшихся var_info

    def work(self, var_info):
        if var_info in self.key_info_cache:  # var_info есть, быстрый поиск из кеша
            self.key_info_cache[var_info]['count'] += 1
        elif var_info in self.key_info_contains:  # var_info есть, но лежит в БД
            if len(self.key_info_cache) > self.max_contains:
                self.drop_from_cache()  # дропнуть чтобы не было memoryError
            self.key_info_cache[var_info] = self.select_from_sqlite3(var_info)  # найти var_info в БД
            self.key_info_cache[var_info]['count'] += 1
        else:  # новый var_info
            self.drop_from_cache()
            self.key_info_cache[var_info] = {'count': 1, 'reg': None, 'oper': None, 'time_use': set(), 'imeis': set()}
            self.key_info_contains.add(var_info)

    def drop_from_cache(self):
        key = next(iter(self.key_info_cache))
        val = self.key_info_cache.pop(key)
        self.insert_to_sqlite3(key, val)
        return key, val

    def insert_to_sqlite3(self, key, val):  # положить var_info в БД

    def select_from_sqlite3(self, key):  # найти var_info в БД

ob = CacheKeyInfo()
for file in tuple_of_files:
    for row in wb[first_sheet].rows:
        var_info = ...
        ob.work(var_info)
```

А в качестве оптимизации вашего кода:

```
if var_info not in key_info:
    ...
elif var_info in key_info:
    ...
```

Следует заменить на

```
if var_info in key_info:
    ...
else:
    ...
```

Comment: Спасибо, это может помочь. Только я не понял строку: self.key_info_cache[var_info] = self.select_from_sqlite3(var_info)     Разве она не добавит новый ключ со значениями в основной словарь и не создаст тем самым вновь угрозу MemoryError? Или я не так понимаю?

Comment: для избегания этого, перед добавлением новой записи, есть self.drop_from_cache(), который удаляет от туда одну запись и помещает ее в БД, там самым освобождая память для добавления новой записи

Answer (score 0):

А результат в итоге идёт в какой-то файл excel? Можно было бы после каждой итерации обработки файла класть в результирующий excel и обнулять словарь, тем самым наращивая результирующий excel файл. Либо просто всё коммитить в БД и потом уже работать с ней, селект из БД в любом случае выполнится быстрее чем вы будете обрабатывать результирующий excel файл (если он имеется)

Comment: Так не получится.. Словарь должен существовать до последнего, так как значения ключей словаря меняются постоянно и ключи должны быть уникальны. Допустим после итерации я записал их в EXCEL файл и очистил словарь. Потом начал заново заполнять словарь - уже записанный в EXCEL ключ может встретиться повторно, таким образом в EXCEL в итоге будут внесены уже не уникальные значения. И эти дублирующиеся ключи будут содержать сведения с неполными анализами, которые не сопоставить друг другу.